# Why do I have to assign a new array so that every dynamic object (component) gets deleted?

Tags: qt, qml

I have a JS array that I use in QML. In this array I store many dynamic objects(components) that I create and show in my application window. I also have a clear all button that is supposed to delete all items by iterating through that array. I use delete and then `shift()` to remove the items, however for some reason not every object gets deleted or removed. Why is that?

This is the code that is not work:

```
Button
{
    id: clearallButton
    width: 60
    height: 25
    text: qsTr("Clear all")

    onClicked:
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < canvas.componentvect.length; ++y)
        {
            canvas.componentvect[y].destroy();
            canvas.componentvect.shift();
        }                        
    }
}
```

And this is the code that has been working for me:

```
Button
{
    id: clearallButton
    width: 60
    height: 25
    text: qsTr("Clear all")

    onClicked:
    {
        for (var y = 0; y < canvas.componentvect.length; ++y)
        {
            canvas.componentvect[y].destroy();                            
        }
        var emptyvect=[];
        canvas.componentvect=emptyvect;
    }
}
```

When I try variant 1, it only removes some objects and some still remain? Why is that? I call delete on every object and `shift()` to remove it from the array. Shouldn't every object be removed then as it does in example 2?

Comment: Usually I go with the second method of going through the entire array and destroying elements in one pass then assigning a new empty array. It feels much cleaner than using some method (ambiguously?) named "shift".

Comment: Shift() does the opposite of pop() and removes the first element in the array. But I just had a logic mistake here. But a question to you since u use the second method. By just deleting all the elements and then assigning a new array without ever removing those elements from the original array, doesn't that lead to memory leaks?

Comment: I believe JS has a garbage collector, unlike C/C++. Meaning there shouldn't any difference in manually removing the item and throwing them all away by assigning a new array (i.e. removing references to destroyed items).

Comment: You are right! I come from C++ mostly and only use little JavaScript for QML so I didn't think about that. Thanks for clarification! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I feel very stupid now. By using shift() inside the loop the iteration doesn't work properly because if the iterating variable destroys object on position 0 and then I use shift() the object that was supposed to be at position 1 moves to position 0. Was a logic mistake my bad.

This is the updated code and it works:

```
onClicked:
{
    while(canvas.componentvect.length !=0)
    {
        canvas.componentvect[0].destroy();
        canvas.componentvect.shift();
    }
}
```